# RabbitMQ accepting connections but closing them before accepting any input

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I just installed the latest version of rabbitmq and I've been trying to get it to work. The server is running and I've restarted it once just to be sure it's a consistent problem.

If I `telnet localhost 5672`, I get

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

As you can see, the connection is accepted but rabbitmq does not accept any input. The connection is closed immediately. No further information shows up in logs.

`rabbitmqctl` works without any problems.

This is running on Windows Subsystem for Linux / Ubuntu. I don't have any other options for a local dev environment because I'm on a work computer which is locked down pretty tightly.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into the same issue, using Ubuntu(16.04) as a subsystem on Windows and rabbitmq 3.7.8. I noticed that when running `sudo rabbitmqctl status` the listeners showed the following:

```
{listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]}
```

I fixed this issue by creating a rabbitmq config file and specifying the localhost and port 5762

Here is what i did step by step.

1. Using sudo && vim, I created a 'rabbitmq.conf' file, located in
   /etc/rabbitmq/

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/rabbimq/rabbitmq.conf
   ```
2. I specified the localhost(127.0.0.1) and port(5672) for the default
   tcp listener in the rabbitmq.conf file

   ```
   listeners.tcp.default = 127.0.0.1:5672
   ```
3. Restart rabbitmq

   `sudo service rabbitmq-server stop`

   then

   `sudo service rabbitmq-server start`
4. Check `sudo rabbitmqctl status` and look at the listeners, you should see your new tcp listener with the localhost ip sepcified

   {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"127.0.0.1"}]}

Here is the [config docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#erlang-term-config-file) from rabbitmq that may help clarify some of these steps.

Comment: you save me. 
tks

Answer (score 1):

Telnet lets you confirm the system is listening and allows incoming connections.
But even an "out of the box" install of RabbitMQ expects credentials for connections.

`rabbitmqctl list_users` to see which users are configured.

If guest present, typical creds are guest / guest

Either install management plugin (or confirm it is installed),
or script your test, most languages have a package available for connecting to RabbitMQ.

Comment: I understand this. Thing is, Telnet is just making the TCP connection which is getting closed immediately by rabbitmq and thus does not even have time to authenticate.

Comment: Telnet command is trying to connect to RabbitMQ using the telnet _protocol_ which RabbitMQ is not supporting. So trying to test connection cannot be done properly through this tool. If you need to test the connection, look for example for a python library and do it from python through that library.

Comment: Right protocol or not, telnet is a pretty good tool for sanity checks on TCP since the only byte with any special meaning is 0xFF. I've used it before to do manual testing of HTTP servers back in college when we learned how the http protocol works.