# RabbitMq with WSL and python

Tags: python, ubuntu, rabbitmq, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed RabbitMq on Ubuntu 18.4 via WSl (with the store). Downloaded the last stable release as deb, followed by sudo apt-get install -f to fix the dependencies.
Then I have create a .py file with the first example of the RabbitMq website:

```
import logging
import pika

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
connection =
pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key='hello',
                  body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

but I get the following error (running in Ubuntu or from windows):

```
coval@LAPTOP-PVGUIGKO:~/work/testMQ$ python3 send.py
DEBUG:pika.adapters.select_connection:Using EPollPoller
DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': <bound method Connection._on_connection_start of <SelectConnection CLOSED socket=None params=<ConnectionParameters host=localhost port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>, 'one_shot': True, 'only': None, 'arguments': None, 'calls': 1}
DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': <bound method Connection._on_connection_close of <SelectConnection CLOSED socket=None params=<ConnectionParameters host=localhost port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>, 'one_shot': True, 'only': None, 'arguments': None, 'calls': 1}
DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': <bound method _CallbackResult.set_value_once of <pika.adapters.blocking_connection._CallbackResult object at 0x7fa7c6057d88>>, 'one_shot': False, 'only': None, 'arguments': None}
DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': <bound method _CallbackResult.set_value_once of <pika.adapters.blocking_connection._CallbackResult object at 0x7fa7c6057e08>>, 'one_shot': False, 'only': None, 'arguments': None}
DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': <bound method _CallbackResult.set_value_once of <pika.adapters.blocking_connection._CallbackResult object at 0x7fa7c3e5fe08>>, 'one_shot': False, 'only': None, 'arguments': None}
DEBUG:pika.adapters.select_connection:call_later: added timeout <pika.adapters.select_connection._Timeout object at 0x7fa7c31fe978> with deadline=1529463117.2377074 and callback=<bound method Connection._on_connect_timer of <SelectConnection INIT socket=None params=<ConnectionParameters host=localhost port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>; now=1529463117.2377074; delay=0
INFO:pika.adapters.base_connection:Pika version 0.12.0 connecting to 127.0.0.1:5672
ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Read empty data, calling disconnect
INFO:pika.connection:Disconnected from RabbitMQ at localhost:5672 (-1): EOF
ERROR:pika.connection:Incompatible Protocol Versions
ERROR:pika.connection:Connection setup failed due to The protocol returned by the server is not supported: (-1, 'EOF')
DEBUG:pika.callback:Processing 0:_on_connection_error
DEBUG:pika.callback:Calling <bound method _CallbackResult.set_value_once of <pika.adapters.blocking_connection._CallbackResult object at 0x7fa7c6057d88>> for "0:_on_connection_error"
DEBUG:pika.callback:Processing 0:_on_connection_closed
DEBUG:pika.callback:Calling <bound method _CallbackResult.set_value_once of <pika.adapters.blocking_connection._CallbackResult object at 0x7fa7c3e5fe08>> for "0:_on_connection_closed"
DEBUG:pika.callback:Incremented callback reference counter: {'callback': <bound method Connection._on_connection_start of <SelectConnection CLOSED socket=None params=<ConnectionParameters host=localhost port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>, 'one_shot': True, 'only': None, 'arguments': None, 'calls': 2}
DEBUG:pika.callback:Incremented callback reference counter: {'callback': <bound method Connection._on_connection_close of <SelectConnection CLOSED socket=None params=<ConnectionParameters host=localhost port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>, 'one_shot': True, 'only': None, 'arguments': None, 'calls': 2}
ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Connection open failed - The protocol returned by the server is not supported: (-1, 'EOF')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
  File "/home/coval/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 377, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/home/coval/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 417, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/home/coval/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 469, in _flush_output
    raise maybe_exception
pika.exceptions.IncompatibleProtocolError: (-1, 'EOF')
```

It looks like RabbitMq runs on the default port with the default parameters:
[image]

```
{
  "rabbit_version": "3.7.6",
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "guest",
      "password_hash": "0OxxjMIoTzeL48fpAUU12wXwOqX3ZOJCrU2f76TlneyB8TGJ",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": "administrator"
    }
  ],
  "vhosts": [{ "name": "/" }],
  "permissions": [
    {
      "user": "guest",
      "vhost": "/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    }
  ],
  "topic_permissions": [],
  "parameters": [],
  "global_parameters": [
    { "name": "cluster_name", "value": "rabbit@LAPTOP-PVGUIGKO.localdomain" }
  ],
  "policies": [],
  "queues": [],
  "exchanges": [],
  "bindings": []
}
```

Is there anything special to configure?

Comment: Are you sure it's listening on localhost? You need to have a listener on "127.0.0.1" or alternatively "0.0.0.0" - this looks like it is bound to IPv6 only.

Comment: There have been reports of issues running RabbitMQ on WSL. Please note that there is a Windows-native installation for RabbitMQ available, as well as Windows-native Python. I would try both of those next.

Comment: No way to make it work... I have same problem with java client and the problem again is WSL and Microsoft... Use native Windows rabbitmq distribution.

Comment: This solution fixed my problem (I had exactly the same problem that you)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285088/rabbitmq-accepting-connections-but-closing-them-before-accepting-any-input